# Is it possible to use Can? in ActiveAdmin controllers (using cancancan gem)

Tags: activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

Does `can?` actually work in AA? Using AA 2.6.1 and Rails 6 and Ruby 2.6.5.

I see in the [latest AA documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.md) and many other posts that the `can?` method should be callable within AA resource controllers e.g.

```
index do
  column :title, sortable: false
  column :secret_data if can? :manage, Post
end
```

However if I add such if statements to my `:index` columns, I will get an error.
"undefined method `can?' for nil:NilClass"

This is a simple context which should work for starters, but what I want to do is somewhat more complicated.

I have an AdmixUser model and a Group model, and a nested resource Grouprelationship that stores the role of an AdmixUser in a Group. On the Group#show page there is a  table_for a group's relationships as follows:

```
table_for resource.grouprelationships do
  column :action_test do |gr|
    para link_to "Edit Relationship", edit_admix_grouprelationship_path(gr.id)
 end
end
```

and in my `Ability.rb`:

```
    can :read, Grouprelationship, group_id: mygroups
    can :update, Grouprelationship do |gr|
      user_role=Grouprelationship.find_by(admix_user_id: user.id, group_id: gr.group_id).role
      return true if user_role==Grouprelationship::PI #PI can do anything
    end
```

The logic here is that if my role in a Group is the 'PI' then I alone can update the role of others in the Group.

This logic is working correctly as far as AA goes. If a non-PI user follows the `link_to` in the table, it certainly executes the block in the Ability class, and the controller will flash a notice that the action is not authorized.  But it would be cleaner not to offer links to unauthorized pages in the first place. If I change the `link_to` line to:

```
para link_to "Edit Relationship", edit_admix_grouprelationship_path(gr.id) if can? :update, gr
```

then it throws the same undefined method error.

It is hard to find recent discussion of the `can?` method in AA.  In older times e.g. [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/oarvjq/rails-activeadmin-and-cancan), it seems it was necessary to modify the resource's controller with `load_and_authorize_resource` but this method does not exist in my AA controller.

So finally the question is how to configure the resource so that `can?` is enabled, or else what am I doing wrong?

There might be some complication because I am using a custom user model "admix_user" and namespace "admix" but I appear to have set this up correctly since CanCanCan authorization is working in every AA context except the above use of `can?`

Answer (score 0):

reading the AA documentation, the correct usage is not `can?` but instead `authorized?`. i.e. in my controller the table displays correctly when I use

```
table_for resource.grouprelationships do
  column :action_test do |gr|
    para link_to "Edit Relationship", edit_admix_grouprelationship_path(gr.id) if authorized? :update, gr
 end
end
```

does the job. I was confused because of the conflicting documentation: [here](https://activeadmin.info/3-index-pages/index-as-table.html) where `can?` is used and [here](https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html#setting-up-your-own-authorizationadapter) where `authorized?` is defined.